# JMeter MergeResults is not handling timeStamp label correctly (millis)

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

Created two dummy sample projects as (dummy1.jmx and dummy2.jmx) and executed below commands with default settings (JMeter 5.3 default installation with all required plugins installed).

1. **#> jmeter.bat -n -t dummy1.jmx -l dummy1.csv -j dummy1-jmeter.log** to execute load

   Generated report and timestamps look perfect both in dashboard and graphs

   **#> jmeter.bat -g dummy1.csv -o dummy1 -j dummy1-report-jmeter.

[image: dummy1 html report]

2. **#> jmeter.bat -n -t dummy2.jmx -l dummy2.csv -j dummy2-jmeter.log** to execute load

   Generated report and timestamps look perfect both in dashboard and graphs

   **#> jmeter.bat -g dummy2.csv -o dummy2 -j dummy2-report-jmeter.log**

[image: dummy2 html report]

3. Used MergeResults plugin to merge the above CSV files to a single file and generated HTML report

   **#> JMeterPluginsCMD.bat --generate-csv dummy1-dummy2.csv --input-jtl merge.properties --plugin-type MergeResults**

   Found merged timeStamp label is not valid and also generated report shows invalid DateTime.

   **#> jmeter.bat -g dummy1-dummy2.csv -o merged -j merged-report-jmeter.log**

[image: Merged Report]

Is this a bug or am I missing configuration? Even adding **jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS** to user.properties didn't help

merge.properties

```
inputJtl1=dummy1.csv
prefixLabel1=TEST1:
includeLabels1=.*
excludeLabelsl=
includeLabelRegex1=true
excludeLabelRegex1=
startOffset1=
endOffset1=


inputJtl2=dummy2.csv
prefixLabel2=TEST2:
includeLabels2=.*
excludeLabels2=
includeLabelRegex2=true
excludeLabelRegex2=
startOffset2=
endOffset2=
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately we cannot help without:

1. Seeing your `merge.properties` file contents
2. Knowing what do you expect

In the meantime I can only tell you where did this `2000-01-01` date came from:

- It's declared [here](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/tools/mergeresults/src/main/java/kg/apc/jmeter/vizualizers/MergeResultsGui.java#L112):

  ```
  private static final long REF_START_TIME = 946681200000L;
  ```
- And being added to the original SampleResult timestamp [here](https://github.com/undera/jmeter-plugins/blob/master/tools/mergeresults/src/main/java/kg/apc/jmeter/vizualizers/MergeResultsGui.java#L317):

  ```
  res.setTimeStamp(res.getTimeStamp() - startTimeRef + REF_START_TIME);
  ```

I don't know whether it is a bug or it's designed to work like this (however the crazy logic of substraction of sampler start time from its timestamp is beyond my limited understanding), it's better to check at [JMeter Plugins support forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins)

In the meantime you can use services like [BM.Sense](https://sense.blazemeter.com/) for comparing different test runs resutls

Comment: merge.properties added - if i look start timeStamp in dummy1 is 1601979532356 and in dummy2 is 1601979846170 but merged results starts from 946681200000
'timeStamp,elapsed,label,responseCode,responseMessage,threadName,dataType,success,failureMessage,bytes,sentBytes,grpThreads,allThreads,URL,Latency,IdleTime,Connect
946681200000,86,TEST1:sys1/api/esb/1.0/configuration,200,OK,SYS2_CONFIG_REQUESTS-ThreadStarter 2-1,text,true,,114,0,1,16,null,47,0,3'